# Routing to npm modules fails

Tags: playframework, npm

I'm trying Angular2 together with Play2 to try them out.
But I have a problem with my routing:

```
# Home page
GET     /                           controllers.Application.index()

# Map static resources from the /public folder to the /assets URL path
GET     /assets/*file               controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file)
GET     /app/*file                  controllers.Assets.at(path="/public/javascripts", file)
GET     /node_modules/*file         controllers.Assets.at(path="/node_modules", file)
```

I get the following error:
[link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9wDiT.png)

The assets are not routed correctly, but the paths are right. Does anyone know how to help me? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I found out, in order for Play to recognize the folder, it has to be in the `public` directory. No matter if the paths are correct or not

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have the `node_modules` folder in the project root folder?

If yes, and if it works correctly in the development mode `activator run` but did not work in the production mode, then the problem is that you did not package the `node_modules` folder. You need to add it to the `build.sbt`:

```
// Add additional folders to the prod 
mappings in Universal ++=   
  (baseDirectory.value / "node_modules" * "*" get) map
    (x => x -> ("node_modules/" + x.getName))
```

Comment: Yes the folder is there, and no, I'm still in development mode (in the IDE) It works when I delete the route and simply copy the folder in the public folder, but that's not really a solution
EDIT: I tested your addition to the build.sbt and the errors are still the same